# Overloaded template operator calling separate class operator

Tags: c++

I've got a template class containing a priority queue of other classes, I need to use the priority overloader to call the individual class overloaders to compare based on the individual classes preferences (in this case it's age, in another class it could be price.

I've got absolutely no doubt that I've implemented the operator overloading incorrect so would appreciate the advice.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

using namespace std;    

class Animal {
    public:
        Animal();
        Animal(string t, int a);
        int get_age()const;
        bool operator< ( Animal& b) const;
        void display()const;
    private:
        string type;
        double age;
};

void Animal::display() const
{
    cout << "Type: " << type << "    Age: " << age;
}
int Animal::get_age() const
{
    return age;
}

Animal::Animal(){}

Animal::Animal(string t, int a)
{
    type = t;
    age = a;
}

bool Animal::operator< ( Animal& b) const
{
    return b.get_age();
}

template<typename T>
class Collection {
    public:
        Collection();
        Collection(string n, string d);
        void add_item(const T& c); 
    private:
        priority_queue <T> pets;
        string name; // Name of the collection
        string description; // Descriptions of the collection
};

template<typename T>
Collection<T>::Collection(){}

template<typename T>
Collection<T>::Collection(string n, string d)
{
    name = n;
    description = d;
}

template<typename T>
bool operator<(const T& one, const T& two) 
{
     return one.operator<(two);
}

template<typename T>
void Collection<T>::add_item(const T& c)
{
    pets.push(c);
}

int main(){
    Animal p1("Dog", 10);
    Animal p2("Cat", 5);
    Animal p3("Turtle", 24);
    Collection<Animal> P("Pets", "My Pets");
    P.add_item(p1);
    P.add_item(p2);
    P.add_item(p3);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error and I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it. I've got to keep the class overloader as the single variable (Animal& b).

> task.cpp: In instantiation of 'bool operator<(const T&, const T&)
>   [with T = Animal]':
>   c:\mingw-4.7.1\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_function.h:237:22:
>   required from 'bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&)
>   const [with _Tp = Animal]'
>   c:\mingw-4.7.1\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:310:4:   required from 'void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator,
>   _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >; _Distance = int; _Tp = Animal; _Compare =
>   std::less]'
>   c:\mingw-4.7.1\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_heap.h:442:4:   required from 'void std::make_heap(_RandomAccessIterator,
>   _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >; _Compare = std::less]'
>   c:\mingw-4.7.1\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/include/c++/bits/stl_queue.h:393:9:   required from 'std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence,
>   _Compare>::priority_queue(const _Compare&, const _Sequence&) [with _Tp = Animal; _Sequence = std::vector >; _Compare = std::less]' task.cpp:57:45:   required from 'Collection::Collection(std::string, std::string) [with T = Animal;
>   std::string = std::basic_string]' task.cpp:79:43:   required
>   from here task.cpp:66:30: error: no matching function for call to
>   'Animal::operator<(const Animal&) const' task.cpp:66:30: note:
>   candidate is: task.cpp:36:6: note: bool Animal::operator<(Animal&)
>   const task.cpp:36:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from
>   'const Animal' to 'Animal&' task.cpp: In function 'bool
>   operator<(const T&, const T&) [with T = Animal]':

Comment: It is written in the error message change the code to this: `bool Animal::operator< ( const Animal& b) const` If the parameter is not of const reference type (it was `Animal&`), you cannot call this operator with a const argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison

```
bool Animal::operator< ( Animal& b) const
{
    return b.get_age();      // returns true always unless age == 0 
}
```

is no comparison and it should take a `const` parameter. You should have something like

```
bool Animal::operator< (const Animal& b) const 
                       // ^----------------------- const !
{
    return get_age() < b.get_age();
}
```

Btw you dont need to use a member `operator<` for the priority queue. Especially if you want to sort objects in different ways I would recommend to not use it, but pass a lambda to the `priority_queue`. See eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) for an example.

Comment: Thank you! I added a const in each location one at a time but not together. I'm a bit confused why we need to do that so I'll have to google it some more

Comment: @Sarah as a rule of thumb you can declare every method as `const` and only if it needs to modify members you remove the `const`. Also note that adding `const` isnt sufficient... it may compile but you will run into trouble if you dont fix the comparsion into really doing a comparison. See the other answer for more details on that

Comment: @Sarah it's actually the template operator <, which you don't need at all, which is calling the member `<` with `const` both sides. However, the advice to `const` qualify as much as possible is good

Answer (score 0):

Both of your overloads of `<` are problematic

```
bool Animal::operator< ( Animal& b) const
```

the `Animal` should also be `const`. You also need to **compare** both parameters, otherwise things (such as your `priority_queue`) that expect `<` to provide an ordering will have undefined behaviour.

You don't use anything non-public from `Animal`, so I suggest you change it to

```
bool operator< (const Animal & lhs, const Animal & rhs)
{ return lhs.get_age() < rhs.get_age(); }
```

This has the benefit of treating both sides identically, rather than one being implicit.

```
template<typename T>
bool operator<(const T& one, const T& two) 
{
     return one.operator<(two);
}
```

This template matches **all types** and is **entirely superfluous**. `a < b` can call *either* a member or a free `operator <`. Just delete this template.